# How do I remove the white corners from my TabBar when running under iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uitabbar

I'm trying to make my app look good under iOS 6 but am finding I have white corners with a black tip on the bottom edges of my tab bar.  Any ideas how I can get rid of this effect?

Running on iOS 6

[image]

Close up of the white artefact

[image]

Running on iOS 7 (happy with this on iOS 7)

[image]

Comment: Change tabbar button image size .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the [JASidePanelController](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) we're using for our [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) style slide-out side menu has the following method which the JASidePanelController calls when setting itself up: (due to the rounded corners applied under iOS 6, as mentioned by the developer in the header declaration)

```
- (void)stylePanel:(UIView *)panel {
    panel.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
    panel.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

To remove the corners I overrode the method in my subclass

```
- (void)stylePanel:(UIView *)panel {
    [super stylePanel:panel];

    [panel.layer setCornerRadius:0.0f];
}
```

Weird corners are now gone on iOS 6, and everything looks fine on iOS 7 :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually solved by setting the `masksToBounds` property of the `layer` of the object to YES.

```
 nameOfTabBar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

If `nameOfTabBar` doesn't have that property, then you'll have to find the `UIView` or `UIImageView` that is the source of those white corners.